# Display value of a textbox inside another textbox using AngularJs on button click

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

New in AngularJs. Finding it complex a little. I have created two text box and a button. Now I want, first I will write something inside the first text box. Then I will click on the button. After that the value of the first text box will get displayed inside the second text box. I have written very little code, I didn't even mentioned the button click function as I am confused on that. Please help me to go further.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="type">
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="button" onclick="myFunction()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="display" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your controller do ,

```
$scope.myFunction = function () {
    $scope.display = $scope.type;
}
```

in your html you have to change onclick to ng-click,

```
<input type="button" value="button" ng-click="myFunction()" />
```

see this plunk for example, http://plnkr.co/edit/c5Ho1jlixwZFx7pLFm9D?p=preview

Comment: Can you please explain because I am not understanding that in controller where should I place the code..

Comment: i have attached the plunk, see it to understand

Comment: I am working in mvc, and in webapplication, in both of then ng-click, ng-app this all are showing error. Why? What thing i need to add to remove the errors from the "ng" tag

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have included angular js file in your HTML.

//add below snippet in your HTML head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">     </script>
```

Comment: //add below snippet in your HTML head tag

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: if not..donwload angular js file and save it locally and add the local path in your HTML head tag

Comment: I have downloaded angular.min.js file and added it in my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80649/discussion-between-amit-and-umesh-kolapkar).